# How do I apply custom rendering to all form fields except for certain field types in a Symfony 2.1 project

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have created a form theme for my project with the following contents:

```
{% block field_row %}
<div class="row">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
</div>
{% endblock field_row %}
```

I apply this theme to the project globally and now all my form fields get the additional css class 'form-control'.

I now however want to limit this override to only form fields that are *not* **choice** & **checkbox** field types.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit annoyed when I did something similar as it was more complicated than I thought it should have been.
There may be a better way but this is what worked for me.

```
{% block form_row %}
    {%  set choice = false %}
    {% if not form.vars.compound %}
        {% for prefix in form.vars.block_prefixes %}
            {% if prefix == 'choice' %}
                {%  set choice = true %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if choice %}
        <div class="row">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>      
    {% else %}       
        <div class="row">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
        </div>  
    {% endif %}   
{% endblock form_row  %}
```

I would recommend using `form_row` instead of `form_field` to ease any future transition to to 2.3+ as `form_field` has been remove from symfony 2.3+ but `form_row` works in 2.1.